# How is the average salary calculated for time spend outside Germany

Tags: income-tax, germany

I spent the last few years working and paying taxes in the US with salary X. I then moved to Germany where I get salary Y. This is also the first time I pay taxes in Germany. Within one year of the move I would like to apply for "Elterngeld" after childbirth happens in Germany. The basis of the calculation for the "Elterngeld" is the average netto salary of the last 12 months. How is the netto salary determined in this case?

There is surprisingly little online information about this situation. I would appreciate a sourced answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I phoned the responsible people. And want to share the answer in case anybody has the same issue:

**Income not taxed in GER/EU/EWR is counted as zero. In other words the rolling average is still over 12 months whereas the foreign months are counted as zero income.**

Comment: That’s amazing. So if you went from a high paying job in the USA to an equally high paying job in Germany, you would get this benefit for a few months.

Comment: @gnasher729. Tell me about it. Before 2011 any foreign income was counted towards the average. Apparently this new rule was implemented to make it fairer for the user. Despite the fact that this new rule can only reduce the final amount.